# How to try normal shutdown and then force a shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown

Is there a command for Windows to try the normal shutdown, and if not success, force shutdown automatically after 1 minute?

I tried:

```
shutdown -f -s -t 60
```

But I got a terminal printing infinitely:

```
C:\Users\Wellington\Desktop>shutdown -f -s -t 60
C:\Users\Wellington\Desktop>shutdown -f -s -t 60
C:\Users\Wellington\Desktop>shutdown -f -s -t 60
```

And I'm not sure if this will try the normal shutdown first...

Comment: Your command looks correct and should work as you intend, except if Windows itself is somehow stuck. Try running the [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) command. Does Windows shut down correctly when you do it thru the Start menu?

Comment: If you change that command from shutdown (could be a batch file somewhere in your path named shutdown.cmd doing something weird) to shutdown.exe does the problem repro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK,there is no direct command to run but you can modify your above command to fulfill your requirement as like this.

> shutdown -s -t 60 && shutdown -f
>
> shutdown -s -t 60 || shutdown -f

Try this,It will first do a normal shutdown after 1 minutes if it fails then it will execute force shut down.

or you can write a batch file with using if(condition) and simply run it.

Comment: I don't really see the difference between this and the command used by the poster.

Comment: yes there is no difference but a little the above will not execute force shut down until the normal shut down fails.

Answer (score 0):

do it in powershell?

```
Start-Job -name shut -ScriptBlock {Stop-Computer}
Wait-Job -Name shut -Timeout 60
Stop-Computer -Force
```

Just run it in a powershell console or paste that into a 'shutdown.ps1' text file, then right click 'run in powershell'.

Answer (score 0):

The below command will shutdown your computer after 60 seconds and if it fails it'll forcefully shut it down.

```
shutdown -s -t 60 -f
```

Answer (score 0):

`shutdown -s -t 60 && timeout 60 && shutdown -f -s -t 00`